# Moving tcolorboxes inside beamer frames

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox

Let's assume we have a tcolorbox in the following environment:

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\usepackage{listings}
%
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=boxtitle,width=250pt, move downward= 10pt]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX]
    code...
\end{lstlisting}    
    Some text
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]

more code...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I move the `tcolorbox` I buildt, to the position I desire (in the frame)? I have tired to move it via `[move downwards*= 9pt]`but that gives me the exception :

`Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/enhanced' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...h=280pt, boxrule= 2pt, move downward= 10pt]`

Also, I saw a post about embeeding the `tcolorbox` inside a ´node´ or ´tlrbox´ but I didn't really understand how that is done.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: before `fcolorbox` try to add `\vspace{10pt}` or if you like to have it vertical centered  `\vfill`. in case that you like to have also horizontal centered than trx `\vfill\centering
\begin{tcolorbox}...`

Comment: `\tcbuselibrary{skins}` to use the `enhanced` key. Is `17pt` actually supported by Beamer? That is enormous relative to the size of the slides. The default is 11pt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always include the `tcolorbox` inside a `TikZ` node and place it over certain position of `current page` (you need two compilations to get the box on desired position).

`move downward` is not defined as option in `tcolorbox`, therefore the error is normal.

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%
\usepackage{listings}
%
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{test}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]%
\node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=boxtitle,width=250pt]%, move downward= 10pt]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX]
    code...
\end{lstlisting}    
    Some text
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]

more code...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}};
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{test}
\tikz[remember picture, overlay]%
\node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south east] at (current page.south east) {%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=boxtitle,width=250pt]%, move downward= 10pt]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX]
    code...
\end{lstlisting}    
    Some text
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]

more code...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]